# What is the use case behind this complicated TypeScript contraption?

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon an example.
First a function and it's return type are defined

```
interface ResponseData {
  data: string[];
  hasMoreItems: boolean;
}
const getData = (): Promise<ResponseData> => {
  const data = {
    data: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    hasMoreItems: false
  }
  return Promise.resolve(data);
}
```

Now, here is the confusing part

```
type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? U
  : T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U
  ? U
  : T extends Promise<infer U>
  ? U :
  T;
type PromiseResult = Unpacked<ReturnType<typeof getData>>;
// PromiseResult = ResponseData
type FunctionResult = Unpacked<() => string>;
// FunctionResult = string
```

How is `Unpacked<T>` of any use as we already have `interface ResponseData`?

Comment: Its purpose is to "unpack", as the name implies. The function might return a promise or an array or another value-returning function, or simply a value. Those types appear to be trying to express what the underlying data is, whether it's provided directly or indirectly. I suppose the idea is that you can freely change the return type of getData in just 1 single place and everything else will update as a consequence, but we can't read the author's mind any more than you can.

Comment: "I suppose the idea is that you can freely change the return type of getData in just 1 single place and everything else will update as a consequence"  yeah, this makes sense.